# How to register file assocation in a separate component in WiX

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, installation

I'm trying to make a separate **feature** for registering a file association in WiX installer:

```
<Feature Id="AssociationFeature" Title="File Association" Description="Register file association">
  <ComponentRef Id="AssociationComponent" />
</Feature>
```

However, the parts responsible for registering a file association and installing the executable itself are located in **different components**:

```
<!-- Component containing application executable -->
<Component Id="ExeComponent" Guid="F183BFA1-A7AB-45E4-1FB7-0A680826C58E">
   <File Name="my-application.exe" Id="Executable" />
</Component>

<!-- Component registering the file extension association -->
<Component Id="AssociationComponent" Guid="1575A831-5FE0-4720-9646-535C88CDE46B">
  <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\my-application.abc" Name="FriendlyTypeName" Value="My Application" Type="string" />
  <ProgId Id="my-application.abc">
    <Extension Id="abc">
       <Verb Id="Open" TargetFile="Executable" /> <!-- This gives the error -->
    </Extension>
  </ProgId>
</Component>
```

This leads to the following error:

> error LGHT0204 : **ICE69**: Mismatched component reference. Entry '...' of the Registry table belongs to component '`AssociationComponent`'. However, the formatted string in column '`Value`' references file '`Executable`' which belongs to component '`ExeComponent`'. Components belong to different features

Is there any way to register a file association in a separate component different from the executable?

Comment: Perhaps explain what problem you're trying to solve with this. Why a separate component?

Comment: @PhilDW As I wrote at the beginning of the post, I want to have it as separate **feature** so the user could check/uncheck it.

Comment: Try to use `TargetProperty` instead of `TargetFile`. Set the property to the absolute path of the executable. The [docs for ICE69](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/ice69) explain why you can't reference another component.

Comment: @johndoe: but separate feature does not mean separate component. Hence the question. It's not clear why you can't have a feature with the shortcut+component  and another feature with just the component.

Comment: @PhilDW The executable component *must* be installed, it's not a `feature`. But users can choose a `feature` - to register file association with this executable or not to register. I'm new to Wix, but if I understand correctly, this leads us to having two separate components.

Comment: @zett42 Thanks a lot. Could you add your comment as an answer so I accept it?

Answer (score 0):

The general way to deal with this is to have two components. Both contain the file, but only one component contains the shortcut. At install time just choose the appropriate component. As long as the conditions on the components (or the features) ensure that both components won't be installed, this just works.